# Optimising a Get Next Value List function

Tags: c#, list, do-while

We retrieve a list of objects from a database and cannot rely on the Id order to guarantee they will be in the right sequence, as objects may have been edited, deleted etc.

They look like this:

```
Id   NextId

1    3
2    0
3    17
17   2
```

So the correct order is 1, 3, 17, 2.

I came up with this code to solve the problem:

```
            long lastStep = steps.Single(x => x.NextId == 0).Id;
            //Probably should be a guard clause for nulls

            List<MyObject> orderedSteps = new List<MyObject>();
            int retries = 0;

            do
            {
                foreach (var entry in steps)
                {
                    if (lastStep == entry.NextId) orderedSteps.Add(entry);
                    retries++;
                }
            } while (orderedSteps.Count() < steps.Count() && retries < 10000);

            //Flip the order so it runs first to last
            orderedSteps.Reverse();

            return orderedSteps;
```

I think this works...but it feels kind of hacky, and that there's a more safe and efficient way of doing it.

Any Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Can we safely assume that NextId is unique, and that there are no closed loops in the data?

Comment: Yes, NextId should always be unique.  There should always be a NextId 0 for the last step - if there isn't we want to throw!

Comment: I'd suggest creating a `Dictionary<int, int>` with `NextId` as the key and `Id` as the value.  That way, you can quickly find the record that points to the current one without searching the set multiple times.  You could only have one `NextId` with the value 0, though.

Comment: Those are basically "linked lists".  Before I offer a solution I'd like to point out that the representation allows for single orphans, multiple chains, invalid links (to nonexistent items), loops (including single item loops), branches (two or more items each claiming the same ID is next) and does not represent where the "head" is (although the first element of each chain can be inferred).  It's also not intrinsically necessary that 0 is a special "null" ID, apart from convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this directly in the database using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH SequenceQuery (Id, NextId, Ordering)
AS
(
  SELECT Id,
         NextId,
         0 AS Ordering
    FROM Steps
    WHERE Id = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Steps.Id,
         Steps.NextId,
         SequenceQuery.Ordering + 1 AS Ordering
    FROM SequenceQuery INNER JOIN Steps
      ON SequenceQuery.NextId = Steps.Id
)
SELECT *
  FROM SequenceQuery
  ORDER BY Ordering
```

In the event of a cycle, this will return an error once it hits the maximum recursion depth. The maximum depth is by default 100; if your data set could legitimately have more than 100 elements, you can increase the limit with the following clause (which goes right at the end of the query, after the `SELECT` statement):

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) -- (for example)
```

This will be by far the fastest way to get the data back, provided that the `Id` column is properly indexed.

If you prefer to do it in code, then you'll need to load the entire table into a dictionary beforehand and then walk through it. The advantage to this is that you can explicitly detect cycles instead of depending on a numeric limit to the number of levels.

```
var steps = ...;

var stepById = steps.ToDictionary(step => step.Id);

var stepsInOrder = new List<int>();
var visited = new HashSet<int>();

// Make sure that when we hit 0, we'll definitely stop.
Debug.Assert(!stepsInOrder.ContainsKey(0));

int currentStepId = 1;

while (stepById.TryGetValue(currentStepId, out Step step))
{
  stepsInOrder.Add(currentStepId);

  int nextStepId = step.NextId;

  if (!visited.Add(nextStepId))
    throw new Exception($"Cycle found at step {nextStepId}");

  currentStepId = nextStepId;
}
```

(SQL tested, C# code untested)

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer Jonathan.  Unfortunately we're using Redis caching for some of the data retrieval so SQL isn't an option (not mentioned in the question as I wanted to simplify the problem for easier consumption).  However the recursive C# I will take a good look at now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution.  Requires several assumptions to be true:  Single chain, terminated with a 0 Id.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id;
    public int NextId;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Item {0} (links to {1})", Id, NextId);
    }
};

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Item[] items = new Item[] {
            new Item() { Id = 1, NextId = 3 },
            new Item() { Id = 2, NextId = 0 },
            new Item() { Id = 3, NextId = 17 },
            new Item() { Id = 17, NextId = 2 }
        };

        Dictionary<int, int> idToIndex = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        int headId = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < items.Length; ++index)
        {
            idToIndex.Add(items[index].Id, index);
            headId = headId ^ items[index].NextId ^ items[index].Id;
        }
        int currentId = headId;
        while (currentId != 0)
        {
            var item = items[idToIndex[currentId]];
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            currentId = item.NextId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a curious trick with the exclusive ORs, but wouldn't it make more sense for the caller to supply a starting `Id`? In the original question, the process started with `Id` value `1`. Is there a reason to prefer a dictionary mapping `Id` values to indices as opposed to a dictionary mapping `Id` values directly to `Item` objects?

Comment: @JonathanGilbert, It's not a trick.  It's finding the element that is not referenced - which is therefore the start of the chain.  (Assuming it is a single chain)  It does so by finding the id that is not used as a NextId. Assuming no duplicates, it's a valid approach.  The convention of using 0 for the null reference is the "trick" I suppose.  It would be fine to supply the starting Id, if you know it, yes.  You could map to Item objects too that's fine - doesn't work with value types though.

Comment: That is a good point about value types, though my feeling here is that it is probably a win on the algorithmic complexity side to just not use value types in this scenario. Technically, for what the OP presented, straight up copying of value types wouldn't actually cause a problem here though.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Wyck!

Comment: I have to give a +1 for that XORring.  So it assumes that everything that appears once as a `NextId` will also appear once as an `Id` (and therefore cancel itself out), except for `NextId = 0` (which won't change the output), and the single `Id` value that is not referenced (which will be the output).  Nice :D

Comment: That's exactly right, @Trevor.  Thanks for adding the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is as follows:

```
class MyObject
{
    public long Id;
    public long NextId;
    public override string ToString() => Id.ToString();
};

public void q48710242()
{
    var items = new[]
    {
        new MyObject{ Id = 1, NextId = 3 },
        new MyObject{ Id = 2, NextId = 0 },
        new MyObject{ Id = 3, NextId = 17 },
        new MyObject{ Id = 17, NextId = 2 }
    };

    var nextIdIndex = items.ToDictionary(item => item.NextId);
    var orderedSteps = new List<MyObject>();

    var currentStep = new MyObject() { Id = 0 };
    while (nextIdIndex.TryGetValue(currentStep.Id, out currentStep))
    {
        orderedSteps.Add(currentStep);
    }
    orderedSteps.Reverse();

    var output = string.Join(", ", orderedSteps);
}
```

Returns:

> output = "1, 3, 17, 2"

This uses a dictionary to build an index of the items as in Jonathan's answer, but by using `NextId` as the key.  The algorithm then proceeds backwards from the 0 as in the original question to build the list in reverse.  This approach has no problems with loops in the data as any such loop will never be entered *assuming that `Id` is unique*.

If the data contains multiple elements with the same NextId, then it forms a tree structure:

```
var items = new[]
{
    new { Id = 1, NextId = 3 },
    new { Id = 2, NextId = 0 },
    new { Id = 3, NextId = 17 },
    new { Id = 17, NextId = 2 },
    new { Id = 100, NextId = 2 }
};
```

This will cause the `.ToDictionary()` call to fail with `System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.`

If the data contains no entries with a `NextId` equal to 0, it will return an empty list.

**Update** Changed to return a list of objects rather than the indices.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm, are you sure this is immune to cycles? What happens if you change the line in the seed data adding pair `{ Id = 3, NextId = 17 }` to instead add `{ Id = 2, NextId = 17 }`?

Comment: @JonathanGilbert While you're correct that the change causes an infinite loop, I was making the _assumption_ (possibly incorrectly) that the `Id` field in the data was necessarily unique.

Comment: The difference between the `Id` field being unique and the `NextId` field being unique is that as an `Id` of `0` is not valid, this algorithm cannot enter a loop to start with.  Consider input data of `{ Id = 1, NextId = 3 }, { Id = 2, NextId = 0 }, { Id = 3, NextId = 1 }`.  Both fields are unique, but starting with `Id = 1` enters an infinite loop, whereas starting with `NextId = 0` produces a chain of one element.

Comment: @JonathanGilbert I've updated my answer to state the assumption.  Thanks